# Can an external hard drive damage an internal hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

I have an external hard drive of 2TB that accidentally felled and it wasn't showing data on my laptop. I searched to find out if its a hardware damage then I found out that pc is detecting an external hard drive it's running fine(by which I mean without weird sounds to indicate physical damage to the rotating part ). but I'm not able to read or write on the drive its showing unallocated
[image: computer management screenshot]

And as you can see I'm unable to initialize as well. I used Argus Monitor to see the S.M.A.R.T. report about it it showed this

[image: caution for reallocated memory something]

and I think that the current pending sector value is increasing every time I plug the drive in. I thought I can try to repair the drive but after all this I did I saw that SMART started showing caution for my internal Hard Drive as well somehow

[image: SMART for internal drive]

Even when external was not plugged in I am afraid that if this can damage my internal drive? And how can I fix this issue with an internal as well as an external hard drive? I have very important data on the external hard drive which I want to extract.

[image: SMART caution notification]

Comment: It certainly looks like you have two failing disks. Current-Pending/Reallocated sectors tend to increase exponentially as time goes on. They are amongst the most serious of HDD issues, because they indicate your data is being damaged. Replace them as quick as you can.  You may want to try a tool like DDRescue to try to move the data onto new media. it will try its best to recover data from bad sectors.

Comment: `Can an external hard drive damage an internal hard drive` .. no, it can't

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas but this caution against internal Hard drive wasn't there before

Comment: @FrankThomas the reallocated sectors are constant for a few days for the internal drive but external one is rapidly increasing. My Hard internal Hard disk got corrupted once before. Do you suggest if i have to change the internal one i should prefer a SSD rather than HDD as i think its more safe?

Comment: since it is a laptop, and you've already had the external fall off the table, SSDs are much more impact-resistant. SSDs can have a shorter lifespan for workloads where disk is mostly full and the data is being overwritten again and again, but generally speaking, a good SSD is less likely to die as the result of physical considerations.

Comment: It is easy to assume because something is happening.. that it was caused by another thing.  Sometimes things just happen and sometimes things even happen in tandem.  Back in my days of doing support I can't tell you how many times people assumed that our program ruined their computer.. of course it didn't.  S*it just breaks and SOMETHING is happening when it does.

Comment: I would suggest OP to backup data from the internal drive and replace both drives. External drive failure is definitely not related to the internal drive errors.